# Animations not working outside of parent component in React 16.13.1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-animations, styled-components, keyframe

I'm facing a problem where if I separate my child components outside my main component, my keyframe animations stop working.

The animation in question is a simple expanding container, which plays every time the content of a container changes.

My Abouts.js (main component):

```
const About = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [ topic, setTopic ] = useState('react')
  const [ logo, setLogo ] = useState(topicsList[0].logo)
  const [ active, setActive ] = useState(0)
  
  ...

  const handleTopicChange = (topic, index, logo) => {
    setTopic(topic.toLowerCase())
    setLogo(logo)
    setActive(index)
  }

  //Creates buttons from a list of topics and adds the functionality to switch between them
  const createButtons = () =>
    topicsList.map((topic, index) => (
      <Button
        key={topic.name.toLowerCase()}
        onClick={() => handleTopicChange(topic.name, index, topic.logo)}
        active={active === index}
      >
        {topic.name.toLowerCase().includes('csharp') ? 'C#' : topic.name.toUpperCase()}
      </Button>
    ))
  
  ...

  //Renders the Container with content based on the topic hook which gathers content from an i18next file
  const Topic = props => {
  const value = props.value.includes('c#') ? 'csharp' : props.value
  return (
    <TopicContainer>
      <TopicTitle
        style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}
        $color={props.theme === dark ? dark.colors[value] : light.colors[value]}
      >
        {t(`titles.about.${value}`)}
      </TopicTitle>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.children }} />
    </TopicContainer>
    )
   }

   return(
   ...
   {createButtons()}
   <Topic theme={props.theme} value={topic}>
      {t(`paragraphs.${topic}`)}
   </Topic>
   ...
)
}
```

My styles.js (Styled Components file):

```
...

const expand = keyframes`
  from {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1); 
  }
`

const expandAnimation = css`
  animation: css`${expand} 300ms ease`;
`

const blogText = css`
  font-size: ${props => props.theme.fonts.size.xs};
  font-weight: ${props => props.theme.fonts.weight.normal};
  color: ${props => props.theme.colors.neutralLight};
  @media ${device.greaterThan.laptopLMin} {
    font-size: ${props => props.theme.fonts.size.md};
  }
`

export const TopicContainer = styled.div`
  ${expandAnimation};
  ${blogText};
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  & div {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
  }
  & p {
    width: 100%;
    @media ${device.greaterThan.laptopLMin} {
      width: 70%;
    }
  }
`
...
```

Now, everything works perfectly fine, and as intended. The problem is that when I move the child (**Topic**) component outside of its parent (**About**) component, my animations stop working (except for the first render a.k.a. when you refresh the page). Even though the content inside the container changes just as before, and I'm not getting any negative messages in my console.

I would have specified that I'm using Styled Components, but I tried to create a css file for the same purpose, in case the problem had something to do with Styled Components, but the result was the same. Everything works perfectly fine until my child moves out...

Please let me know in case there is a lack of information.

Answer (score 0):

For you animation to run you need to pass either props.main or props.signature to down to styled component

```
const expandAnimation = css`
  animation: ${props => (props.signature || props.main ? 'none' : css`${expand} 300ms ease;`)};
`const expandAnimation = css`
  animation: ${props => (props.signature || props.main ? 'none' : css`${expand} 300ms ease;`)};
`
```

Your TopicContainer should be;

```
let isSignature=true;
let isMain=true;

   <TopicContainer signature={isSignature} main={isMain}>
      <TopicTitle
        style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}
        $color={props.theme === dark ? dark.colors[value] : light.colors[value]}
      >
        {t(`titles.about.${value}`)}
      </TopicTitle>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.children }} />
    </TopicContainer>
```

Since I did not find any reference to the signature or main i am creating dummy variables to pass as prop.

Comment: Both props (signature and main) are actually used explicitly to prevent animation. Since I'm using this container for a static block on my page as well. As such, I intentionally am not passing those props to the container in question. My operator is saying that if neither of these props are true then animate.

Comment: I edited the props away from the presented code to prevent confusion.

Comment: If you don't mind can you share the repo or gist it's little difficult to figure out the flow